# Reverse Query Through Django Template File

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

models.py file

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

views.py file

```
class company_detail(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        company = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        context = {'company': company}
        return render(request, 'crm/company_detail.html', context)
```

company_detail.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>{{company.name}}</li>
    </ul>


    {% for company in object_list %}
         {{ company.name }}
         {% for Contact in company.contact_set.all %}
             {{Contact.first_name}}
         {% empty %}
            <!-- no entries -->
         {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

</div>



{% endblock content %}
```

I'm trying to get the Contacts who are under that company to show up on the company_detail.html page. How do I reverse query it properly to show all Contacts under that company?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `object_list` in your `DetailView`'s context, only the object. You need to remove the for loop over `object_list` in the template

```
 {% for contact in company.contact_set.all %}
     {{ contact.first_name }}
 {% empty %}
    <!-- no entries -->
 {% endfor %}
```